# Determine modulation function from spectrum?

Tags: frequency-spectrum, distortion

I have a two periodic signals $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ which are related to each other by a periodic modulation function $\alpha(t)$:
$$y(t) = \alpha(t) x(t)$$
If $x(t)$ is a sinusoid, is it possible to determine $\alpha(t)$ from the spectrum of $y(t)$? How might I do this?

Comment: Your formulation is a bit strange. So all these are periodic. Do you mean your message is repeated in time? or you just talk about one period?

Comment: This looks like what every generic AM radio demodulator accomplishes (during those times when some solo musical instrument is playing some constant pitch).

Comment: Also, is it a strict requirement to look at the spectrum? A [product detector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_detector) can also do what you want...

Answer (score 1):

The Fourier transform is reversible, so the same amount of information is contained in the spectrum (not in the *power spectrum*, that doesn't contain the phase, and hence, only half of the information)! Just convert your spectrum back to time domain.

However, if you just got the power spectrum plot of a signal, you'll find that many modulations have "characteristic" spectral shapes. With a bit of practice, you can tell binary GMSK from an 4-FSK pretty easily.

Now, in general, the problem of detecting a signal and its modulation is pretty hard – governments pay loads of money for well-working signal classificators, because in many cases, you're looking at a very weak $y(t)$ within a mixture of hundreds, and it's still hard to guess whether you're looking at an 16-QAM or an 8-PSK if you don't have timing information.

Thus: without a lot of additional info on what you're looking at, guessing the modulation *class* of $\alpha$ from $|Y(f)|$ is very hard. And it's harder to actually estimate $\alpha(t)$ from that.